# ActionBar Tab with Home Icon

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

Basically I want this:

```
 __________________________________
|      |      |      |      |      |
| Home | Tab1 | Tab2 | Tab3 | Tab4 |
|______|______|______|______|______|
|                                  |
|               My App             |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
...
```

The "Home" is not a section, its just the icon, so it can't be clicked. The rest of the tabs are functional.

The question is, how to position the Tab navigation buttons beside the icon?

**EDIT:** I'm using `ActionBar`, `FragmentPageAdapter` and `Fragments`

Comment: What are you using to manage your tabs ? Do you have an adapter, do you use viewpager ?  maybe ABS ? Please add more detail

Comment: have you look at the docs? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Comment: Yes, I already read the docs, but there is no documentation for specifically position the tab navigation button to the right of the icon

Comment: what do you mean, the docs clearly show the tabs to the right of the app icon...

Comment: Yes it does, but only for wider screens as tablets, I need it for phones too

Comment: Or for phones in landscape mode. I want it for portrait mode too: Lets say I have 2 tabs, and their titles are "1", "2". There IS enough space for both to be besides the icon, but on portrait it stills goes in a row below and they take 50% width each one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need to do is set the navigation type of the actionbar

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                   .setText(R.string.artist)
                   .setTabListener(new TabListener<ArtistFragment>(
                           this, "artist", ArtistFragment.class));
actionBar.addTab(tab);

tab = actionBar.newTab()
               .setText(R.string.album)
               .setTabListener(new TabListener<AlbumFragment>(
                       this, "album", AlbumFragment.class));
actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

which is right from the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

**EDIT**

As CommonsWare pointed out which I forgot to include is that the tabs only appear in the actionbar in landscape mode and if you have too many tabs to fit in the actionbar they get compressed to dropdown navigation

Comment: This is both right and wrong. It is right, as it is the only way to get tabs in the action bar. It is wrong, in that the tabs will rarely be where the OP wants them. They may appear in a row below the action bar (e.g., phones in portrait). They may be converted into a drop-down navigation list instead of tabs (see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24439).

Comment: The problem here is that the tabs appear in a row below the row in which the icon is displayed. I need the Icon and the tabs button to be in the same row.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco If you read my edit you will see why, doing this is the only way to put tabs in the actionbar, you will need to implement your own view if you do not like this result ie. not use the actionbar

Comment: I think you mean landscape mode, cause it only works on landscape. Is there any way for it to work on portrait too?

Comment: no there is not and yes I meant landscape. you will have to create your own view to do what you want and not use the actionbar

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Perhaps consider accepting the answer then? :)